# Font face rendering on actual Kindle Fire but NOT online KDP Kindle Previewer

Tags: font-face, media-queries, epub, kindle-fire

I have a font face loaded for KF8 and it shows up perfectly on the desktop previewer and on my physical Kindle Fire. However, when I load it onto the KDP online previewer, it ignores the font entirely and resorts to the default font settings.

Has this happened to anyone? Are there "safe" KF8 fonts that you've been able to render on the online previewer? Tangerine is a Google web font, only available as a ttf, but I've converted it to an otf and woff, and tried it as such but to no avail. I need a script font for this book of poetry.

Would there be a media query to target the online previewer?

Also, will wrong font (default Kindle font) on the online previewer be what is shown on the Look Inside preview?

My CSS:

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: "Tangerine_Bold.ttf";
    src: url("Tangerine_Bold.ttf");
}
```

More CSS in a amzn-kf8 media query:

```
.section {
    font-size: 2.3em;
    font-family: "Tangerine_Bold.ttf", serif;
}
```

OPF:

```
<item id="font2" href="Tangerine_Bold.ttf" media-type="application/x-font-ttf"/>
```

I've also tried it as font/ttf and that worked fine, too.

The font looks superb on the actual Kindle. Please help! Amy

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm having exactly the same issue. I've found that what is happening (by using 7zip to extract the .mobi from the online previewer) is that the `font-family` attribute is stripped from the css, as well as html by amazon's server. Same for `font` and `<font family="somefont">`. I've contacted amazon, but haven't heard back yet

Answer (score 0):

The Kindle Previewers, either on-line or stand-alone app, are not guaranteed to be a completely faithful replica of what happens on every device. I have the same problem, actually, with the Nook web previewer (which is also what people use to view samples of a book before buying); it doesn't display data URI-based images (showing a little broken GIF icon instead). In any case, why are you concerned that the KDP previewer is not showing your font?